# Controller URI Issue - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Not a back-end guy by any means, but can navigate my way through the basics. My question is this, I have the below function for a benefits page I'm doing. Wanted to simplify the sub-pages versus creating multiple controller functions and route redirects. So I decided to go the URI as a variable route...not sure if this is clean way of doing it or not (usually I only go this route when dynamically creating pages via db). But it works.

If I go to `website.com/benefits/{section}` the IFs work as they should. However, if I go to `website.com/benefits/` I get a 404 page - obviously. I have nothing to handle that request - only because I don't know how. How do I redirect to the home page is a user visits `website.com/benefits/` and no uri (i.e. $section) was defined?

**EDIT:** Or would it be wise to just create a separate `function benefits(){}` function along with the one below? Is this good practice?

Controller function:

```
function benefits($section)
{
    if($section == 'fitness')
    {
        echo('fitness page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'health')
    {
        echo('health page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'beauty')
    {
        echo('beauty page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'sports')
    {
        echo('sports page!');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "the home page" you want to redirect? Did you mean `redirect('/');` is "redirect to the home page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect seems to be giving 404. If you want to access `/benefits/`, just make a default case (in your case, the else part).

But see what I did - I've set up a default value for $section to index, so that would denote your index page, making all unspecified value do the redirect:

```
function benefits($section = 'index')
{
    if($section == 'fitness')
    {
        echo('fitness page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'health')
    {
        echo('health page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'beauty')
    {
        echo('beauty page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'sports')
    {
        echo('sports page!');
    }
    elseif($section == 'index')
    {
        echo('benefits index page!');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

But, since the question is not very clear, there could be another solution.

Make sure your controller is called 'Benefits', and rename your function to 'index'.
This would work for URLs like site.com/benefits.

See more info about using controllers [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html).

Comment: I should have been more clear...the redirect works fine. It's pretty much there if anyone types in a uri that's not one of the `$section`'s IF values. My problem is, if no uri is specified after `/benefits` in the url. I short, if no uri was entered in the url and the visitor went to `website.com/benefits`, there's no function to handle that request. You dig? The redirect above is only if $section value doesn't exist.

Comment: Got it, then it's probably the second solution. If you can show the whole controller, I could tell you what's wrong right away.

Comment: This is pretty much all that's in the controller at this point - for this page anyways. So do you think it's wise to create a `function benefits(){}` function that's separate from the `function benefits($section){}` above to handle the index request?

Comment: No, that won't handle the index request (it doesn't work like in C, for example), but you need to name your function 'index'. Can you edit the question and show the whole file benefits.php?

Comment: Can't share the entire file....tons of other code in it. It's a "content" controller with a benefits page portion in it. Technically the page is website/com/content/benefits. But I routed the URL. What I posted is all I have for the benefits.

Comment: Oh, I see, so you forgot to mention routing (was it there in the original question?). Anyway, that's **key** element here. To solve the problem, just create another route before your current one, and make sure you route content/benefits (with nothing after) to your benefits/index (and use if $section == index part I gave you). To make sure we're clear: you'll have two routes for benefits - one for benefits/ and the other for benefits/whatever.

Comment: Shit, sorry. That makes sense. Should have mentioned that. :) This works...thanks. But seems quite messy overall (my code). Would there be an easier way, in your opinion?

Comment: Well, I rather keep routes for exception cases (if any) and stick to the standard structure overall. But again, depends on the app and how much you plan to expand it later.

Comment: You might be right. Creating a separate Benefits controller may be the best route in this instance...

Comment: @MikeBarwick why you have to handle the `$section == 'index'` case when you just want to redirect to the home page as you said?

Comment: @anvoz Did you even bother reading the part about routing? And no, once again, your solution doesn't solve it since it works exactly the same in this case.

Comment: @Shomz Assume that he used `$route['benefits/?(.*)'] = 'content/benefits/$1';`, my solution will work exactly the same like you said. But if he did use that route, he could "redirect to the home page is a user visits website.com/benefits/" without any problem. That's why I want to ask why he should handle the `index` case. It's possible that he could not find his root problem yet.

Comment: @anvoz But I'm saying that your code and OP's code work the exactly the same, try it. The default value doesn't change anything because anything that's not 'fitness', 'health', etc, would go under else and thus cause redirection.

Comment: @Shomz You're right about my solution only if he uses that route which he didn't mention in his question. Also he said "If I go to website.com/benefits/{section} the IFs work as they should" which means if `section` is not 'fitness', 'health', etc then it will get into the `else` case and redirect. So my solution may not wrong in this part. I just want to ask about the `index` thing and try to find out his root problem.

Comment: @anvoz Correct, and thus he already had the code that worked just like yours, so it's not the solution. He probably made a mess with routing and will have a much better app once he rewrites it not to rely on routing for everything. The index thing is that there is a root page (/) and the benefits index page (/benefits).

Answer (score 0):

<s>You may try this (add default function parameter value) to redirect to the home page when you visit `website.com/benefits/`: `function benefits($section = FALSE) {}`</s>

I was missing the fact that you have to use routing rule for this. In sum up, you want the route to handle 2 scenarios:

1.Go to `website.com/benefits/{section}`: echo something
2.Otherwise, go to `website.com/benefits/` or the `section` was not defined in IFs statements: redirect to the home page (`website.com/`)

In fact, `website.com/benefits/` is not a separated case, it should belong to the `else` case literally. You just want to handle the `else` case correctly but got a bug when you access `website.com/benefits/`. You don't want to handle the `index` section if you don't need to. So you probably use a wrong routing rule.

I tried to reproduce your problem and if you used the setting in the guide of CodeIgniter like `$route['benefits/(:any)'] = 'content/benefits/$1';` you will get a 404 page as you mentioned.

Here is the correct routing rule for your problem, without changing any on your `benefits` function:

```
$route['benefits/?(.*)'] = 'content/benefits/$1';
```

Comment: Is it any different from this solution comparing with your solution when you use `$section = 'index'`?

Comment: Yes, I keep the user on the page when the section is index.

Comment: I think he just want to redirect to website.com/ instead of make another index page for website.com/benefits.

Comment: @MikeBarwick so my solution should work, if it's not, please tell me so I can figure it out.

Comment: @Shomz please check my answer again.

Answer (score -1):

That's the `index` function you are talking about. :D, and the `function index()` is the default function that gets executed if there is no `action` defined in the `url`. No offence, but still not sure what you are doing here.